# Changing background color of jquery-ui button?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui for buttons. The default theme looks great, but I'd like to apply a different background color to a few specific buttons. Is there a way I can easily add another css class to my buttons to just change the bg color of them, without changing any other properties of the button?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just add it to the button's HTML and when the button is created it will get all of the existing classes.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be down voted.  It's a perfectly viable solution.